# How can I display all videos in a directory via html5 and php?

Tags: php, html, html5-video

I am having an issue trying to load multiple videos from a directory on my webserver at one time and display them in a list. Eventually I will want to display the newest 30 posts only but I should be able to figure that out on my own. 
Ffirst off I am able to do this with images but when I try to use video, only one video would load instead of the entire directory.

```
<?php 
$files = glob("uploads/newupload/*.*"); for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++) { $num = $files[$i]; 
$var1 = $_GET["files"]["name"];
print '<a href="'.$num.'">Link to image |</a><br />';
echo '<img src="'.$num.'" width=300 height=240 alt="random image" />'."<br /><br />"; } ?>
```

This is the format I would like the video in,

```
<video width="300" height="240" controls>
<source src="uploads/newupload/1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
<source src="1.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' />
<object id="flowplayer" data="flowplayer-3.2.2.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="300" height="240" >
<param name="movie" value="flowplayer-3.2.2.swf">
<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
<param name="flashvars" value="config={'clip':{'url':'1.mp4','autoPlay':false}}">
</object> 
</video>
```

when I use this code instead of the image code It only displays one video.(and it doesnt play) How can I display all videos in a directory using php?

Here is what i tried
'

```
<?php
$files = glob("uploads/newupload/*.*"); for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++) { $num = $files[$i]; 
print '<video width="300" height="240" controls>
<source src="'.$num.'" type="video/mp4" />';
echo '<object id="flowplayer" data="flowplayer-3.2.2.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="300" height="240" >
<param name="movie" value="flowplayer-3.2.2.swf">
<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
<param name="flashvars" value="config={"clip":{"url":"'.$num.'","autoPlay":false}}">
</object> 
</video>';
?>
```

any help would be great. thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I was able to generate a list of .mp4 videos and have then loop once they play with the code below. I would like to add a still image on the video thumbnails instead of black boxes so i know which ones to click on. also may add the filename next to the videos for identification by using "echo $num;"

```
<?php 

$files = glob("uploads/newupload/*.*"); for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++) { $num = $files[$i]; 
$var1 = $_GET["files"]["name"];
print '<a href="'.$num.'">Share Link to Video |</a><br />';
echo '<video controls loop>
<source src='.$num.' type=video/mp4 width=300 height=240 alt="random image">
</video>'."<br /><br />"; } ?>
```